# read_sql_query parameter is getting split into characters Error : The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 10 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'

Tags: python, pandas

SO I am trying to execute a query through read_sql_query. Following is the construct :

`stocklist = pd.read_sql_query('''select a,b, sum(c) as physcalqty, sum(d) as availableqty from schema.tablename where z = ? group by sourcesystem,stockroom''', connStr1, params=(variable))`

variable='AB00747562'

It seems like from the error message that the string is getting split into its character elements of 10. Can someone shine a light on this.

Comment: `params` should be a list, i.e. `params=[variable]`, otherwise pandas treats your string as a list of 10 separate characters.

Comment: Yes, that worked thanks. A follow up on that, how do I pass a list of values. Something like variables = ['abc1','abc2','abc3'] and this will go as a parameter to sql query

Comment: Yes, correct. Just pass multiple variables in a list `[var1, var2, var3]`. Make sure that the order that variables are in the list matches the order of `?` placeholders in the query.

Comment: Well I dont know how many items will be in the list. I was thinking along the lines of passing the the list of items to the sql query 'in' construct as a parameter list